# Proof of $\mathfrak{S}_F \times_{\mathfrak{S}_H} \mathfrak{S}_G \cong \mathfrak{S}_{F \times_H G}$, categories fibered in sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, higher-category-theory, algebraic-stacks

> **Lemma 3.34:** For $F,G,H$ presheaves in discrete categories/sets: $$\mathfrak{S}_F \times_{\mathfrak{S}_H} \mathfrak{S}_G \cong \mathfrak{S}_{F \times_H G}$$

Proof: The only 2-morphisms of categories fibered in sets are identities.
(Ref: [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dg3215/other/stacks.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edg3215/other/stacks.pdf) )

**Question:** I am not quite sure of the proof where they make use of 2-morphisms of categories fibered in sets are identities in proving the lemma.

Attempt: We want to show an equivalence of categories between $\mathfrak{S}_{F \times_H G}$ and $\mathfrak{S}_F \times_{\mathfrak{S}_H} \mathfrak{S}_G$. It suffices to verify fiberwise that $\mathfrak{S}_{F \times_H G}(S) \cong \mathfrak{S}_F(S) \times_{\mathfrak{S}_H(S)} \mathfrak{S}_G(S)$ for all $S \in \mathfrak{S}$. By lemma $3.9$, $\mathfrak{S}_{F}$ is a fibered category over $\mathfrak{S}$, hence we can use lemma $3.31$ which applies to fibered categories and get $\mathfrak{S}_{F \times_H G}(S) \cong \mathfrak{S}_F(S) \times_{\mathfrak{S}_H(S)} \mathfrak{S}_G(S)$ for all $S \in \mathfrak{S}$. We get an 1-morphism, isomorphism $\alpha: \mathfrak{S}_{F \times_H G} \cong \mathfrak{S}_F \times_{\mathfrak{S}_H} \mathfrak{S}_G$, and we denote the inverse as $\alpha^{-1}$. This is an equivalence since the 2-morphism $(\alpha^{-1} \circ \alpha) \Rightarrow Id_{\mathfrak{S}_{F \times_H G}}$ is the identity, hence a 2-isomorphism. Similarly, $(\alpha \circ \alpha^{-1}) \Rightarrow Id_{\mathfrak{S}_F \times_{\mathfrak{S}_H} \mathfrak{S}_G}$ is a 2-isomorphism.

Recall/Summary (Example 3.8 p17):

The 2-category $\mathfrak{S}_F$:

> Let $F : \mathfrak{S}^{opp} \to Categories$ be a functor (i.e. a
> presheaf of categories). Associate to $F$ the following fibered
> category $\mathfrak{S}_F$ over $\mathfrak{S}$: Objects are pairs $(U,x)$ of objects $U$ in $\mathfrak{S}$ and $x \in F(U)$. Morphisms from
> $(U, x)$ to $(V, y)$ are pairs $(f, \varphi)$ of morphisms $f : U \to
>  V$ and $\varphi : x \to f^* y$, where we write $f^∗ := F(f)$. The
> composition of $(g, \psi : y \to g^∗z) \circ (f, \varphi : x \to
> f^∗y)$ is defined as $(g \circ f, f^∗(\psi) \circ \varphi)$. The
> projection to $\mathfrak{S}$ forgets the second component of the
> pairs.

Comment: The notation is not standard. You should summarise the definitions in the body of your question. Anyway, I think the point is that the (a priori) 2-category of categories fibred in sets is actually a 1-category, 2-dimensional limits reduce to 1-dimensional limits.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why are you referring to 2-dimentional limits (reduce to 1-dimentional limits) instead of 2-morphisms (reducing to 1-morphisms)? So, the isomorphism in my attempt then is enough to show equivalence in the 1-category of categories fibered in sets?

Comment: 2-morphisms don't reduce to 1-morphisms here. They are just trivial.

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you explain '2-dimensional limits reduce to 1-dimensional limits.'?

Comment: I mean that any 1-dimensional limit in a 1-category automatically has the universal property of the corresponding 2-dimensional limit. This is spelled out in jgon's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two points of confusion in the question.

**Point 1: Why are the only 2-morphisms of categories fibered in sets the identities?**

Well, what is a 2-morphism of fibered categories?

Let $A$ be the base category, $P:B\to A$, $Q:C\to A$ fibered categories (over $A$), $F,G:P\to Q$ 1-morphisms of fibered categories (i.e. functors such that $QF=QG=P$). Then a 2-morphism $\alpha:F\to G$ is a natural transformation from $F$ to $G$ with the property that $Q(\alpha_b)=1_{Pb}$ for all $b\in B$ (i.e., $\alpha_b$ lies in the Q-fiber over $Pb$ for all $b \in B$).

In the case that $Q$ is fibered in sets, since $\alpha_b$ is always in the $Q$-fiber over $Pb$ (which is discrete/a set), we have that $\alpha_b$ is an identity morphism. Since $\alpha_b:Fb\to Gb$ is an identity morphism, we conclude that $Fb=Gb$ for all $b\in B$, and for all $f:b\to b'$, the naturality squares force $Ff=Gf$, so $F=G$, and $\alpha=1_F=1_G$.

In other words, if $Q$ has discrete fibers, then the hom categories $\mathbf{Fib/A}(P,Q)$ are also discrete.

**Point 1.5: Implications of Point 1 for 2-fiber products vs 1-fiber products**

Claim: if $R:D\to A$ is a fibered category with discrete fibers, and $P:B\to A,Q:C\to A$ are arbitrary fibered categories, and $F:P\to R$, $G:Q\to R$ are 1-morphisms of fibered categories, then the 1-fiber product $P\times_R^1 Q$ is in fact the 2-fiber product $P\times_R^2 Q$.

Here's a simple proof. Suppose I give you a 2-commuting square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T @>>> P \\
@VVV @VVV \\
Q @>>> R, \\
\end{CD}
$$
then because $R$ has discrete fibers, the only 2-morphism that can make this square commute is an identity, so it actually 1-commutes. Thus there is a unique morphism
$T\to P\times_R^1 Q$. Uniqueness of this morphism guarantees uniqueness up to isomorphism, so this makes $P\times_R^1 Q$ satisfy the universal property of a 2-fiber product of $P$ and $Q$ over $R$.

Alternatively, just check that when $R$ has discrete fibers, the explicit construction of $P\times^2_R Q$ reduces to something isomorphic to the usual construction of $P\times^1_R Q$.

**Point 2: Why does this fact imply the claimed result?**

I'm going to use $\int U$ to denote the category of elements/Grothendieck construction for $U:A^{\text{op}}\to \mathbf{Cat}$, since this is more standard notation in my experience, at least for presheaves valued in sets.

We want to show
$$\int U\times_{\int W} \int V\cong \int U\times_W V$$
where $U\overset{\phi}{\to} W \overset{\psi}{\leftarrow} V$ is a cospan of presheaves of categories, and $W$ is valued in discrete categories.

We know that the fiber product on the left can be taken to be the 1-fiber product when $W$ is a presheaf in $\mathbf{Set}$. Then the objects on the left hand side are tuples
$((a,u),(a,v))$ with $u\in U(a)$, $v\in V(a)$, such that $\phi(u)=\psi(v)$, and morphisms from $((a,u),(a,v))$ to $((a',u'),(a',v'))$ on the left hand side are tuples $((f:a\to a',\alpha : u\to f^*u'),(f,\beta: v\to f^*v'))$, such that $\phi(\alpha)=\psi(\beta)$.

On the other hand, objects on the right hand side are tuples $(a,(u,v))$ with $(u,v)\in (U\times_W V)(A)=U(A)\times_{W(A)} V(A)$, and morphisms $(a,(u,v))\to (a',(u',v'))$ on the right hand side are pairs $(f:a\to a', (\alpha,\beta):(u,v)\to f^*(u',v'))$.

Comparing the data, we see that the two sides consist of the same data, and we can give an isomorphism between the two categories.

**End note**

When $U$ and $V$ are also presheaves valued in sets, this becomes even simpler, since morphisms on the left are now just $f:a\to a'$ such that $u=f^*u'$, $v=f^*v'$, and morphisms on the right are also $f:a\to a'$ such that $(u,v)=f^*(u',v')$.

Comment: Two simple questions I don't understand: (i) In point 1, when the  -fiber over  is discrete/ a set, why is $\alpha_b$ an identity morphism? For instance, if $x,y \in Q-$fiber over $Pb$, and $\gamma:x \to y$ not the identity, can't $Q(\gamma)=1_{Pb}$  (ii) '  is discrete, then the hom categories /(,) are also discrete', is this Hom(P-fiber at a, Q-fiber at a) $\forall a \in A$? Moreover, you showed that all the Q-fibers were discrete, I suppose that implies that Q is discrete?

Comment: For (i), by definition, a category is discrete/a set exactly when there are no nonidentity morphisms, so if $\gamma$ is in the $Q$-fiber and the $Q$-fibers are discrete, then $\gamma$ is the identity. Of course if we don't know that the $Q$-fibers are discrete, then it's perfectly possible for $Q(\gamma)=1_{Pb}$, but $\gamma$ not an identity. This is exactly where we need that $Q$ has discrete fibers.

Comment: For (ii), my wording was a bit careless there. I have edited to say that if $Q$ has discrete fibers, then the hom categories are discrete. The hom category is the full subcategories of the functor category from $B$ to $C$ whose objects are functors $F:B\to C$ with $QF=P$.

Comment: @metalder9 For your last sentence, I should have been more careful in my wording. It doesn't mean anything to say $Q$ is discrete. A fibered category $Q$ can have discrete fibers,  or the underlying category $C$ can be discrete, or the base category $A$ can be discrete, but it doesn't make sense to say $Q$ is discrete. That said, having all fibers discrete doesn't imply that the underlying category is discrete. You can have nonidentity morphisms as long as they don't map down to identity morphisms in the base.